# I am getting unknown value when doing a 4 bit shifter verilog (gate level)

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, fpga, modelsim

I am trying to implement a 4 bit right shifter using gate level but i got unknown result for some reason, my mux work ok but when i try testbench for my shifter it give back something like this:

```
a=0010 b=01 c=0000
a=1111 b=01 c=00xx
```

Please help!!!! Thank you very much

```
module mux2(a,b,sel,c);
output c;
input a,b,sel;
wire net0,net1,net2;
not m1(net0,sel);
and m2(net1,a,net0);
and m3(net2,b,sel);
or m4(c,net1,net2);
endmodule
module mux4(a,sel,c);
output c;
input [1:0]sel;
input[3:0]a;
wire mux_1,mux_2;
mux2 m1(a[3],a[2],sel[0],mux_1);
mux2 m2(a[1],a[0],sel[0],mux_2);
mux2 m3(mux_1,mux_2,sel[1],c);
endmodule

module shift4bitright(c,a,b);
output [3:0]c;
input [3:0]a;
input [1:0]b;
wire [3:0]d=4'h0,d1=4'h0,d2=4'h0,d3=4'h0;
assign d[0]=a[3];
assign d1[0]=a[2]; assign d1[1]=a[3];
assign d2[0]=a[1]; assign d2[1]=a[2]; assign d2[2]=a[3];
assign d3[0]=a[0]; assign d3[1]=a[1];assign d3[2]=a[2];assign d3[3]=a[3];
mux4 m1(d,b,c[3]);
mux4 m2(d1,b,c[2]);
mux4 m3(d2,b,c[1]);
mux4 m4(d3,b,c[0]);
endmodule

`timescale 10ns/1ns
module shift4bitright_tb;
wire [3:0]c;
reg [3:0]a;
reg [1:0]b;
shift4bitright s1(.c(c),.a(a),.b(b));
initial begin
$monitor("a=%b b=%b c=%b",a,b,c);
a=4'h2;
b=2'd1;
#50
a=4'hf;
b=2'd1;
end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

This statement declared a `wire` type signal `d` as well as its driver cone (NOT initial value), which is a constant 0 in this case:

```
wire [3:0]d=4'h0;
```

Just below it, there's another `a[3]` driving `d[0]`:

```
assign d[0]=a[3];
```

This creates a multi-driven logic, hence `x` occurs.

To solve it, change it similar to:

```
wire [3:0] d;
assign d = {3'h0, a[3]};
```